# DML trigger is preventing users from saving manually entered data through EBS

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, dml

I am working on a trigger that will notify employees by email when they become the supervisor of another employee.  It is a compound trigger because old assignment data needs to be queried when a new one is inserted.  It collects relevant data in an indexed table for each row, then processes all of it in the after statement.  The 'email()' procedure and some other names in the code below are placeholders.

The problem occurs when a user manually enters new employee data through EBS, and a new assignment is inserted automatically, which fires the trigger.  Since the assignment record is mostly null, the trigger doesn't ultimately do anything, but the user is unable to save the new employee data they entered.  They don't receive any error message.  When the trigger is disabled the problem goes away, but I can't figure out how it's causing it.  Also, though I left it out of the code here, I have used messages to track exactly what parts of the trigger are executed during testing, and there haven't been any logical errors in this situation.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER APPS.HRSS_SUPERVISOR_UPDATE
FOR UPDATE OR INSERT ON APPS.PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F
COMPOUND TRIGGER
    TYPE assignment_info_r IS RECORD (
        assignment_id           apps.per_all_assignments_f.assignment_id%TYPE
    ,   position_id             apps.per_all_assignments_f.position_id%TYPE
    ,   effective_start_date    apps.per_all_assignments_f.effective_start_date%TYPE
    ,   effective_end_date      apps.per_all_assignments_f.effective_end_date%TYPE
    ,   new_supervisor_id       apps.per_all_assignments_f.supervisor_id%TYPE
    ,   old_supervisor_id       apps.per_all_assignments_f.supervisor_id%TYPE
    ,   updating                BOOLEAN
    );

    TYPE assignment_info_t IS TABLE OF assignment_info_r INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

    assignment_info assignment_info_t; --created an associative array to store data for each row
    l_row_count INTEGER := 0;

AFTER EACH ROW IS
BEGIN
    l_row_count := l_row_count + 1;

    CASE
    WHEN UPDATING('supervisor_id') THEN
        assignment_info (l_row_count).updating := TRUE; --need to know if updating or inserting in the after statement
        assignment_info (l_row_count).assignment_id := :new.assignment_id;
        assignment_info (l_row_count).position_id := :new.position_id;
        assignment_info (l_row_count).effective_start_date := :new.effective_start_date;
        assignment_info (l_row_count).effective_end_date := :new.effective_end_date;
        assignment_info (l_row_count).new_supervisor_id := :new.supervisor_id;
        assignment_info (l_row_count).old_supervisor_id := :old.supervisor_id;
    WHEN INSERTING THEN
        assignment_info (l_row_count).updating := FALSE;
        assignment_info (l_row_count).assignment_id := :new.assignment_id;
        assignment_info (l_row_count).position_id := :new.position_id;
        assignment_info (l_row_count).effective_start_date := :new.effective_start_date;
        assignment_info (l_row_count).effective_end_date := :new.effective_end_date;
        assignment_info (l_row_count).new_supervisor_id := :new.supervisor_id;
    END CASE;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        email(p_recipient => 'developers',
              p_subject => 'errors');
END AFTER EACH ROW;

AFTER STATEMENT IS
    l_position_name apps.hr_all_positions_f.name%TYPE;
    l_old_supervisor_id apps.per_all_assignments_f.supervisor_id%TYPE;
    l_email_address apps.per_all_people_f.email_address%TYPE;

    indx PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
FOR indx IN 1 .. l_row_count
LOOP
IF assignment_info (indx).position_id IS NOT NULL THEN
    BEGIN --need the position name for the following condition
        SELECT DISTINCT hap.name
        INTO l_position_name
        FROM apps.hr_all_positions_f hap
        WHERE assignment_info (indx).position_id = hap.position_id
        AND assignment_info (indx).effective_start_date <= hap.effective_end_date
        AND assignment_info (indx).effective_end_date >= hap.effective_start_date
        AND hap.effective_start_date = (SELECT MAX(hap2.effective_start_date)
                                        FROM apps.hr_all_positions_f hap2
                                        WHERE assignment_info (indx).position_id = hap2.position_id
                                        AND assignment_info (indx).effective_start_date <= hap2.effective_end_date
                                        AND assignment_info (indx).effective_end_date >= hap2.effective_start_date);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            email(p_recipient => 'developers',
                  p_subject => 'errors');
    END;

    IF l_position_name NOT LIKE 'E.%' THEN
    IF assignment_info (indx).new_supervisor_id IS NOT NULL THEN
        BEGIN
            SELECT email_address
            INTO l_email_address
            FROM apps.per_all_people_f
            WHERE person_id = assignment_info (indx).new_supervisor_id
            AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN effective_start_date AND effective_end_date;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                email(p_recipient => 'developers',
                      p_subject => 'errors');
        END;

        CASE
        WHEN assignment_info (indx).updating THEN --check if supervisor has changed
            IF assignment_info (indx).new_supervisor_id != assignment_info (indx).old_supervisor_id OR assignment_info (indx).old_supervisor_id IS NULL THEN
                email(p_recipient => 'supervisor',
                      p_subject => 'new employee');
            END IF;
        ELSE --if inserting, check for previous assignment data
            BEGIN
                SELECT paaf.supervisor_id
                INTO l_old_supervisor_id
                FROM apps.per_all_assignments_f paaf,
                    apps.hr_all_positions_f hap
                WHERE paaf.assignment_id = assignment_info (indx).assignment_id
                AND paaf.effective_end_date = assignment_info (indx).effective_start_date - 1
                AND paaf.position_id = hap.position_id
                AND paaf.effective_end_date >= hap.effective_start_date
                AND paaf.effective_start_date <= hap.effective_end_date
                AND hap.name NOT LIKE 'E.%';
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                    IF assignment_info (indx).new_supervisor_id IS NOT NULL THEN
                        email(p_recipient => 'supervisor',
                              p_subject => 'new employee');
                    END IF;
                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                    email(p_recipient => 'developers',
                          p_subject => 'errors');
            END;
            IF assignment_info (indx).new_supervisor_id != l_old_supervisor_id THEN
                email(p_recipient => 'supervisor',
                      p_subject => 'new employee');
            END IF;
        END CASE;
    END IF;
    END IF;
END IF;
END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    email(p_recipient => 'developers',
          p_subject => 'errors');
END AFTER STATEMENT;
END;
/
```

Comment: You have added condition in no_data_found if new supervisor Id is not null then error message. In this case if new supervisor Id is null then it won’t throw error and won’t insert data

Answer (score 1):

"They don't receive any error message. " smells like a NO_DATA_FOUND.

NO_DATA_FOUND is a PL/SQL exception that tends to be ignored by SQL statements because "I didn't find any rows" isn't an error for a SELECT, INSERT..SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE statements etc. (Arguably it should be for an INSERT..VALUES but it isn't).

I'd put in a bunch of

```
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'No rows for ###');
```

exception handlers for each SELECT ...INTO query in the trigger.

I think around the "SELECT DISTINCT hap.name INTO l_position_name" one, you will probably just want to assign null to l_position_name for a no rows found then carry on into the next iteration of the loop.